# Linq Convert to Custom Dictionary?

Tags: linq, ienumerable, idictionary

.NET 4, I have

```
public class Humi
{
public int huKey { get; set; }
public string huVal { get; set; }
}
```

And in another class is this code in a method:

```
IEnumerable<Humi> someHumi = new List<Humi>(); //This is actually ISingleResult that comes from a LinqToSql-fronted sproc but I don't think is relevant for my question
var humia = new Humi { huKey = 1 , huVal = "a"};
var humib = new Humi { huKey = 1 , huVal = "b" };
var humic = new Humi { huKey = 2 , huVal = "c" };
var humid = new Humi { huKey = 2 , huVal = "d" };
```

I want to create a single IDictionary `<int,string[]>`

with key 1 containing ["a","b"] and key 2 containing ["c","d"]

Can anyone point out a decent way to to that conversion with Linq?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myDict = someHumi
    .GroupBy(h => h.huKey)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.ToArray())
```

Create an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Humi>>` and then project that into a dictionary. Note `.ToDictionary` returns a Dictionary, not an IDictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ToLookup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211.aspx) which allows each key to hold multiple values, exactly your scenario (note that each key would hold an `IEnumerable<string>` of values though not an array):

```
var myLookup = someHumi.ToLookup(x => x.huKey, x => x.huVal);

foreach (var item in myLookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} contains: {1}", item.Key, string.Join(",", item));
}
```

**Output:**

> 1 contains: a,b
>
> 2 contains: c,d